# why contraction mapping theorem fails in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contraction-operator

Suppose $f(x) = \cos x$, then for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{3}]$, we know that there exists a unique fixed point as the mapping $f$ is contraction mapping on $[0, \frac{\pi}{3}]$. One can see this in plot as well. Now consider a smaller set, e.g., $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{6}]$, the mapping $f$ still is a contraction mapping as
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = |\sin \zeta||x-y| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-y|.
$$
However, if you plot it in the graph, you can observe that the graph $\cos x$ does not intersect with $h(x) = x$ in $[0, \frac{\pi}{6}]$, i.e., there is no fixed point in $[0, \frac{\pi}{6}]$. What is possibly going wrong here? What assumptions did I fail to satisfy for the contraction mapping principle?

Comment: $f$ isn't a contraction mapping on $X=[0,\pi/6]$, because it isn't a function from $X\rightarrow X$ at all.  For instance, $f(0)=1 \not\in[0, \pi/6]$.

Comment: See Remark 3 on the Wikipedia page, by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem.  It says, "When using the theorem in practice, the most difficult part is typically to define $X$ properly so that $T(X)\subseteq X$."